# Как выводить названия произвольных рубрик в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Проблема заключается вот в чем. Создал Custom Post Type ( name = film ). И все посты выводится, соответственно, на странице www.site.ru/film. Также создал для данных рубрик кастомные таксономии: год и режиссер. Так вот, как мне в файле archive-film.php вывести рядом с товарами названия рубрик (без ссылок) и ярлык. Т.е, к примеру, у меня в рубрике Режиссер есть "Борис Хлебников", надо вывести имя - Борис Хлебников и Ярлык, который WP сам создает (boris-hlebnikov в моем случае). Искал в гугле, но там другая информация.

Код создания post type

```
function film_create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'film',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Фильмы' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Фильм' )
      ),
      'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
      'year',
      'film',
      array(
        'label' => __( 'Год ' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'works' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );
    register_taxonomy(
      'producer',
      'film',
      array(
        'label' => __( 'Режиссёр' ),
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'works' ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
      )
    );
}
```

Также код achive-film.php

```
  <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'film', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    ?>
      <div class="nearest-slide ">
          <div class="nearest-slide__photo">
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail()?>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="nearest-slide__title">
            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
              <h3><?php the_title()?></h3>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="nearest-slide__line"></div>
          <div class="nearest-slide__paragraph">
            <p><?php echo get_field("film_small")?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="nearest-slide__bottom">
            <div class="nearest-slide__date"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y')?></div>
            <div class="nearest-slide__link">
              <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">
                <svg class="longarrow" width="18" height="18">
                  <use xlink:href="#longarrow"></use>
                </svg>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Добавил код в посте

Comment: Это хорошо, но важнее увидеть код вывода -  archive-film.php

Comment: Добавил и этот код) Но тут стандартный цикл вывода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутрь цикла вывода вставьте

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'producer' );
echo 'Режиссер:' . $terms[0]->name;
echo ' Слаг:' . $terms[0]->slug;
```

Comment: Спасибо но как сделать если надо за пределами цикла?

Comment: Я потому и просил код, чтобы понять, где вы хотите это вывести. За пределами цикла надо знать id поста, чьи термины надо вывести. Откуда этот пост берётся? Покажите код, как вы выводите этот пост за пределами цикла

Comment: Вы все правильно описали. Мне надо вывести его Слаг и в цикле. Но за пределами цикла так же есть Место где мне надо вывести все все произвольные таксономии. Сначала одно , потом другое

Comment: get_terms() https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_terms

Comment: Спасибо большое, все сделал